# x86 ebp's behavior in buffer overflow attack

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, exploit

Looking at a few basic stack-based buffer overflows, I'm confused as to the difference the caller's `ebp` plays in a [basic return address overwrite](https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/classic-stack-based-buffer-overflow/) vs an [off-by-one ebp overwrite](https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/off-by-one-vulnerability-stack-based-2/).

In the return address overwrite, the goal is to smash the stack enough to overwrite the return address and therefore control `eip`.

In the off-by-one attack, the LSB of the caller's `ebp` is overwritten. This forces `ebp` to pop, and the `esp` is moved to a location within the attacker-controlled buffer, which elicits control of the return address and, therefore `eip.

My confusion stems from the behaviour of `ebp`.  In the basic return address overwrite, it doesn't matter that we overwrite the caller's `ebp` with junk bytes, but `ebp`'s value needs to be coherent in the off-by-one attack.  How does the function epilogue work in the basic buffer overflow case?

```
mov esp, ebp 
pop ebp
retn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a basic return address overwrite, as you said you're able to overwrite `ret` directly so only `retn` matters in the instructions of function epilogue.

In an off-by-one ebp overwrite apparently you know you can't overwrite `ret`, but you can pivot the stack to somewhere user controlled.
In this case attacker goes through **two** function epilogue at least to gain control.

1. off-by-one ebp overwrite

   ```
   mov esp, ebp
   pop ebp          ; now ebp is partially overwriten
   retn
   ```
2. pivot stack to controlled area.

   ```
   mov esp, ebp     ; now stack(esp) is moved to controlled area.
   pop ebp          ; controlled
   retn             ; controlled --> gain eip control
   ```

Comment: In the basic buffer overflow we completely overwrite ebp but that doesn't cause a pivot to a garbage address.  What is it I'm not understanding about the difference?

Comment: Stack pivot have to be done by going through **twice** function epilogue. and in a basic return address overflow you gain `eip` control in one overflow, the stack remains unchanged.

Comment: Only `ebp` overwrited do not cause stack changed, overwrited `ebp` must be restored to `esp`, that means twice function epilogues are needed.

Comment: So if I have two functions, the second overwriting LSB of ebp, we won't gain eip until it returns normally via the first epilogue thensforth proceeding to continue until ebp is restored from the caller's [function] epilogue?

Comment: yes, and in practice this trick is usually not for `ret` overwrite but for other like GOT overwrite.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @poming.  I was able to verify this reading here: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~ww6r/CS4630/lectures/Off-by-one-error.pdf.